# Why do I have such a high memory usage for this rioxarray code?

Tags: memory, rioxarray

For my code using rioxarray I am opening quite an amount of raster files. One after another. I even added `del` to remove those from memory, even though I thought it would not be necessary, because they should overwrite each other in the memory.
Nevertheless the RAM usage of the code is high.

The function is as follows:

```py
def write_normalized_raster(parent_folders: List[Path], band_str, resolution) -> None:
    """
    classification bands and raster_paths need to have same order
    :param parent_folders:
    :param band_str:
    :param resolution:
    :return: None
    """

    # ------
    # determine median of each image
    # ------
    local_raster_paths: List[Path] = []
    for parent in parent_folders:
        path = parent / "R{}m".format(resolution)
        path = [x for x in path.iterdir() if str(x).endswith("_{}_{}m.jp2".format(band_str, resolution))][0]
        local_raster_paths.append(path)

    medians: Union[Dict[str, np.float32], Dict[str, Dict[int, np.float32]]] = {}
    # detect clouds
    for raster_path in local_raster_paths:
        tmp_raster = rxa.open_rasterio(raster_path).astype("float32")
        scl = rxa.open_rasterio(get_scl_path(raster_path)).rio.reproject_match(tmp_raster).data

        tmp_data_masked = np.where(np.isin(scl, cloud_classes), np.nan, tmp_raster.data)
        tmp_raster.data = tmp_data_masked

        # median on non-nan pixels
        if len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 2:
            medians.update({str(raster_path): np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked)})
        elif len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 3:
            medians.update({str(raster_path): {0: np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked[0, :, :]),
                                               1: np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked[1, :, :]),
                                               2: np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked[2, :, :])}})
        del tmp_raster
        del tmp_data_masked
        del scl


    # ------
    # determine mean median of all images
    # ------
    if len(medians[str(local_raster_paths[0])]) == 1:
        # mean of median
        avg = np.mean(medians.values())

    else:
        # mean of median
        avg0 = np.mean([x[0] for x in list(medians.values())])
        avg1 = np.mean([x[1] for x in list(medians.values())])
        avg2 = np.mean([x[2] for x in list(medians.values())])

    # ------
    # relevel image intensities
    # ------
    for raster_path in local_raster_paths:
        tmp_raster = rxa.open_rasterio(raster_path)
        original_type = tmp_raster.dtype
        tmp_raster = tmp_raster.astype("float32")
        if len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 2:
            # apply median of median to each raster
            mean = medians[str(raster_path)]
            tmp_raster.data = np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_raster.data, avg), mean)
            save_path = raster_path.parents[0] / (str(raster_path.stem) + "_normalized.tif")
            tmp_raster.rio.to_raster(save_path)
            del tmp_raster

        elif len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 3:
            mean = medians[str(raster_path)]
            tmp_data = tmp_raster.data
            tmp_data[0, :, :] = np.rint(np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_data[0, :, :], avg0), mean[0]))
            tmp_data[1, :, :] = np.rint(np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_data[1, :, :], avg1), mean[1]))
            tmp_data[2, :, :] = np.rint(np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_data[2, :, :], avg2), mean[2]))

            tmp_raster.data = tmp_data

            tmp_raster = tmp_raster.astype(original_type)
            save_path = raster_path.parents[0] / (str(raster_path.stem) + "_normalized.tif")
            tmp_raster.rio.to_raster(save_path)
            del tmp_data
            del tmp_raster
```

I think I am closing or deleting every large object after their usage. Why do still have a memory usage that is rising to 15 GB?

Therefore I profiled the code:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
   199    143.2 MiB    143.2 MiB           1   @profile
   200                                         def write_normalized_raster(parent_folders: List[Path], band_str, resolution) -> None:
   201                                             """
   202                                             classification bands and raster_paths need to have same order
   203                                             :param parent_folders:
   204                                             :param band_str:
   205                                             :param resolution:
   206                                             :return: None
   207                                             """
   208
   209                                             # ------
   210                                             # determine median of each image
   211                                             # ------
   212    143.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       local_raster_paths: List[Path] = []
   213    143.2 MiB      0.0 MiB          22       for parent in parent_folders:
   214    143.2 MiB      0.0 MiB          21           path = parent / "R{}m".format(resolution)
   215    143.2 MiB      0.0 MiB         231           path = [x for x in path.iterdir() if str(x).endswith("_{}_{}m.jp2".format(band_str, resolution))][0]
   216    143.2 MiB      0.0 MiB          21           local_raster_paths.append(path)
   217
   218    143.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       medians: Union[Dict[str, np.float32], Dict[str, Dict[int, np.float32]]] = {}
   219                                             # detect clouds
   220  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          22       for raster_path in local_raster_paths:
   221  15866.0 MiB  16265.2 MiB          21           tmp_raster = rxa.open_rasterio(raster_path).astype("float32")
   222  15987.7 MiB -29038.4 MiB          21           scl = rxa.open_rasterio(get_scl_path(raster_path)).rio.reproject_match(tmp_raster).data
   223
   224  17367.4 MiB  14141.8 MiB          21           tmp_data_masked = np.where(np.isin(scl, cloud_classes), np.nan, tmp_raster.data)
   225  15987.7 MiB -43805.9 MiB          21           tmp_raster.data = tmp_data_masked
   226
   227                                                 # median on non-nan pixels
   228  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21           if len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 2:
   229                                                     medians.update({str(raster_path): np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked)})
   230  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21           elif len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 3:
   231  15987.7 MiB -14832.0 MiB          21               medians.update({str(raster_path): {0: np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked[0, :, :]),
   232  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21                                                  1: np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked[1, :, :]),
   233  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21                                                  2: np.nanmedian(tmp_data_masked[2, :, :])}})
   234  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21           del tmp_raster
   235  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21           del tmp_data_masked
   236  15987.7 MiB -14832.1 MiB          21           del scl
   237
   238                                             # ------
   239                                             # determine mean median of all images
   240                                             # ------
   241  14424.8 MiB  -1562.9 MiB           1       if len(medians[str(local_raster_paths[0])]) == 1:
   242                                                 # mean of median
   243                                                 avg = np.mean(medians.values())
   244
   245                                             else:
   246                                                 # mean of median
   247  14424.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          24           avg0 = np.mean([x[0] for x in list(medians.values())])
   248  14424.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          24           avg1 = np.mean([x[1] for x in list(medians.values())])
   249  14424.8 MiB      0.0 MiB          24           avg2 = np.mean([x[2] for x in list(medians.values())])
   250
   251                                             # ------
   252                                             # relevel image intensities
   253                                             # ------
   254  16694.7 MiB -46947.5 MiB          22       for raster_path in local_raster_paths:
   255  15997.0 MiB -62202.0 MiB          21           tmp_raster = rxa.open_rasterio(raster_path)
   256  15997.0 MiB -51214.2 MiB          21           original_type = tmp_raster.dtype
   257  18071.3 MiB  -8179.1 MiB          21           tmp_raster = tmp_raster.astype("float32")
   258  18071.3 MiB -51307.5 MiB          21           if len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 2:
   259                                                     # apply median of median to each raster
   260                                                     mean = medians[str(raster_path)]
   261                                                     tmp_raster.data = np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_raster.data, avg), mean)
   262                                                     save_path = raster_path.parents[0] / (str(raster_path.stem) + "_normalized.tif")
   263                                                     tmp_raster.rio.to_raster(save_path)
   264                                                     del tmp_raster
   265
   266  18071.3 MiB -51307.5 MiB          21           elif len(tmp_raster.data.shape) == 3:
   267  18071.3 MiB -51307.5 MiB          21               mean = medians[str(raster_path)]
   268  18071.3 MiB -51307.5 MiB          21               tmp_data = tmp_raster.data
   269  18071.3 MiB -51307.2 MiB          21               tmp_data[0, :, :] = np.rint(np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_data[0, :, :], avg0), mean[0]))
   270  18071.3 MiB -51307.2 MiB          21               tmp_data[1, :, :] = np.rint(np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_data[1, :, :], avg1), mean[1]))
   271  18071.3 MiB -51390.6 MiB          21               tmp_data[2, :, :] = np.rint(np.divide(np.multiply(tmp_data[2, :, :], avg2), mean[2]))
   272
   273  18071.3 MiB -51390.7 MiB          21               tmp_raster.data = tmp_data
   274
   275  18416.3 MiB -44147.1 MiB          21               tmp_raster = tmp_raster.astype(original_type)
   276  18416.3 MiB -51390.6 MiB          21               save_path = raster_path.parents[0] / (str(raster_path.stem) + "_normalized.tif")
   277  18074.4 MiB -55087.9 MiB          21               tmp_raster.rio.to_raster(save_path)
   278  16694.7 MiB -75921.3 MiB          21               del tmp_data
   279  16694.7 MiB -46947.5 MiB          21               del tmp_raster
```

To be honest with this report, I am totally unable to find the problem and the reason I am having it.

Comment: You could try setting `file_cache_maxsize`: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.set_options.html

Comment: How big are the files? What happens when you only run with 1-2 files?

Comment: Thanks @snowman2 for the tip, but I set  `xarray.set_options(file_cache_maxsize=2)`, but it didn't result in any change in the ram usage. But calling the garbage collect by myself with `gc.collect()`

Comment: I tried a bit around, using gc.collect() after using del. did help. But I don't know why, because I am lopping and always open the raster in the same object. I dont get the reason. Also adding: `xarray.set_options(file_cache_maxsize=2) ` at the beginning of the function seamed not to cahnge anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem.

One thing I found out: the memory issue only arises in jupyterlab. When I run my script directly the memory is managed properly.

I am using Python 3.8 and jupyterlab 3.